# Are temporary variables released at the end of a statement?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find out when temporary variables are released. I wrote the code below.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        printf("C O\n");
    }
    C(const C&)
    {
        printf("C& O\n");
    }
    virtual ~C()
    {
        printf("C D\n");
    }
};

int kkk(const C&)
{
    printf("kkk\n");
    return 0;
}
int kkk2(int)
{
    printf("kkk2\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    (kkk2( kkk2( (kkk(C()),3) ) ), printf("dsfsdfs\n"), true) && (printf("dsdddf\n"),true);
    printf("=====\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I expect Class C to be released after `kkk` is called, but actually, the result is:

```
C O
kkk
kkk2
kkk2
dsfsdfs
dsdddf
C D
=====
```

I run the code with g++ clang++ and msvc++, the result is same. Class C is release at the end of a statement.

Is it a C++ standard to release temporary variables at the end of a statement?

Comment: The language you are using is C++, not C/C++.

Comment: C++ has no concept of a "sentence".

Comment: There is no C/C++ language standard, because that is not a real language. There is C, and there is C++. They have a few similarities but they are distinct languages. Since your code uses classes, it is C++ because classes don't exist in C. Everything else looks to be have been written in C. You should take a moment to find out the differences between C and C++ and decide which language you intend to use.

Comment: *I try to write the code below*  -- What reason would you write code this way?  To give your coworkers headaches?

Comment: By "sentence" do you mean "statement", as in a line ending with a semicolon?

Comment: I know that I use class, and class is c++. but if I don't use class, I don't know where the temporary variables is release. In c++ I can print out some info in the destroyer. But in C, I can only use structure or small veribles like int float. small veribles veribles will be pass to kkk() through registers. And large structure will be in main's stack when calling kkk(). I want to know when will the large structure be release, But structure can't use destroyer function to print

Comment: structs are no different from classes at all. They have a destructor as well. C++ does not have classes and structs, it has classes, and `struct` and `class` are two keywords to define a class (with different default access)

Comment: @untitled -- As stated, there is no difference between a `class` and a `struct` except for the default access specifier.  It looks like you based your line of thinking on wrong information.

Comment: @untitled Also, in this day and age, it doesn't make a lot of sense to try and beat the compiler at the optimization game.  Maybe 25 or 30 years ago it made some sense to do this, but in this day and age of optimizing C++ compilers, you're basically wasting your time trying to play the optimization game with the compiler.  The worst case scenario is that your code becomes obfuscated (like your code is now), and the code runs **slower** than it should, not faster.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `To give your coworkers headaches?` No. I want to write a class which the constructor is very complicated, and the class has many const veribles. I know the lambda can be used in the constructor initialization list, but a verible in a lambda can't pass to the the other one. So I have to `borrow` stack from the function who call the constructor, by adding a lot of parameters in the constructor function. And then I put all the parameters in a struct, and write a stactic function called construct helper. It is like `A a( new_a(...) );`

Comment: @untitled `(kkk2( kkk2( (kkk(C()),3) ) ), printf("dsfsdfs\n"), true) ` -- There is no guarantee that these arguments will be processed from left-to-right.  That second `printf` could show up first.

Comment: To help people trying to program in **C/C++** programming language, I'm in the process of making a **C/C++** programming language.  It's based on OCaml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Temporary_object_lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime)

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.

> There are two exceptions from that:
> [..]

So to answer your question:

> Is it a C++ standard to release temporary variables at the end of a sentence?

Yes, temporaries are destroyed at end of full-expression (not sentence).

Answer (score 2):

In C++, temporary objects are normally destroyed at the end of the *full-expression*. Normally, this means at the end of the statement in which the temporary object is created. There are some exceptions to this rule, but they don't apply in your situation.

You may be confused by the C++98 concept of "sequence point". The comma operator and the `||` and `&&` operators were sequence points in C++98, however this does not mean that temporary objects would be destroyed upon reaching one of these operators. In any case, the concept of a sequence point was abolished in C++11 (we now say "sequenced before" and "sequenced after").

Answer (score 0):

Yes, temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression (exceptions that don't apply here aside). Usually that is at the next `;`.

If this wasnt the case it would be just too simple to write horribly wrong code. Consider this somewhat contrived example of a function that returns an iterator to a string where it finds a `'c'`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string::const_iterator find_c(const std::string& str) {
    auto it = std::find(str.begin(),str.end(),'c');
    if (it == str.end()) throw "not found";
    return it;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << *(find_c("abc"));
}
```

If the temporary `std::string` would be destroyed right after `find_c` returned as you expect, then `find_c` could not be used with temporaries, because the returned iterator can only be dereferenced while the string is still alive.